# Joint Continuity implies being a Hausdorff space(in the given case)?

Tags: differential-algebra

If we consider G to be the group of non-singular n by n matrices carrying Zariski topology. Then the joint continuity of the multiplication map from 
G x G to G would make G Hausdorff.(We consider the topology in G x G to be the Cartesian product topology of the Zariski topology of G.) Please explain how ?

(Reference- Kaplansky's book 'An Introduction to Differential Algebra')

Answer (score 1):

More generally, the following argument shows that any $T_1$ topological group $G$ is automatically Hausdorff (in fact, a slightly longer argument shows that actually you only have to assume $T_0$).  Here "topological group" means that the multiplication map $G\times G\to G$ and the inverse map $G\to G$ are continuous.  Given this, consider the map $f:G\times G\to G$ given by $f(g,h)=gh^{-1}$.  This map is continuous because the multiplication and inverse maps are.  Since $G$ is $T_1$, $\{1\}$ is closed in $G$, and hence $f^{-1}(\{1\})$ is closed in $G\times G$.  But $f^{-1}(\{1\})=\{(g,g):g\in G\}$ is the diagonal in $G\times G$, and a space $G$ is Hausdorff iff its diagonal is closed in $G\times G$ (if you are not familiar with this fact, it is a good and simple exercise to prove it).

Comment: I think you actually need the result for $T_0$ groups here, because the OP is asking about the Zariski topology, which is usually not $T_1$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass: From context it sounds as though they are talking about the Zariski topology on the $k$-points of $GL_n$ for some field $k$, which is always $T_1$.  Otherwise, I'm not sure in what sense they even mean that it is a "group" (if you are working with schemes, the underlying set of the scheme product $G\times_{\operatorname{Spec} k} G$ is _not_ just the cartesian product of the underlying set of $G$ with itself).

Comment: Not having  the book, I conjectured that the passage cited in the question was intended as a hint why the product topology is not a good idea in the world of schemes. But you're right that he might well be thinking only of closed points, where the product topology is still not a good idea.  (In the case of schemes, I'd say the real reason for not using the product topology is that it doesn't have the universal property of a product, but this group argument could be useful for people who don't appreciate category theory.)